# Why is my import.sql file not automatically running?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, docker, gradle

Working on java spring boot app. Our postgres database is containerized. I can get hibernate to automatically create the tables, but I can't get it to automatically run the import.sql file. Can you please help me figure out what is going on?

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE')
    }
}


apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

mainClassName = 'idealab.IdeaLabMain'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'idealab'
    excludeDevtools = false //TODO(e-carlin): In production this should be removed
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools') // TODO(e-carlin): Make sure this isn't pulled in in the production jar
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
}
```

Here is the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
debug=true

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=docker
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create # TODO(e-carlin): This will wipe away the
                                     # database data. Good for dev not for prod
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Here is the import.sql file located in src/main/resources:

```sql
INSERT INTO color_type (color) VALUES ('blue'),('green'),('purple'),('red');
```

And here is an example of this model:

```java
package idealab.api.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name = "color_type")
public class ColorType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=PrintModel.class, mappedBy="colorTypeId")   
    private Set<PrintModel> printModel;

    @Column(name = "color", nullable = false)
    private String color;

    public ColorType(Integer id, String color) {

        this.color = color;
    }

    //getters and setters
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import.sql` is the Hibernate native feature which will only be executed provided that `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to **create** or **create-drop**.

But now you are setting :

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

- `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` will set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` behind scene .
- `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` is invalid and does not have any effect as all the valid springboot JPA properties should start with `spring.jpa`

So at the end , the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` will be set to **update** and hence `import.sql` will not be executed.

You can simply fix it by changing `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` to :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

*Note : `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` will be overrided by `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` and hence you can simply remove it.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have switched it to what you have said but it is still not loading the data. Any thoughts?

Comment: @moosespirit94 , Sorry about that . I miss the word **properties** .It should be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` . Also please make sure there is no space after "create" . If you simply copy my original answer , it will include space but hibernate will not trim that space automatically and will regards it as an the invalid value. I just try in my local and it work as expected.

Comment: I am getting this error:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized legacy `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value : create

Comment: Figured out my issue - I had a space after create. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear. So consider to vote up my answer or accept it if you found it useful to you ? 

Answer (score 1):

Try after adding the below property,

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

If you're using Spring boot 2, database initialization only works for embedded databases (H2, HSQLDB, ...). If you want to use it for other databases as well, you need to change the spring.datasource.initialization-mode property:

if it doesnt work change the sql file to data.sql and try it.

ref please check the [spring-doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Comment: well ,I guess `import.sql` is the hibernate native feature which is nothing to do with springboot . It will be executed if `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is `create` or `create-drop` . It is nothing to do with embedded database or not ...

Answer (score 1):

We have these properties to create and insert the records into a table. As you only need to insert the records you can remove `spring.datasource.schema`

```
spring.datasource.schema= # Schema (DDL) script resource references.
spring.datasource.data= # Data (DML) script resource references.
```

- No need to change the SQL filenames
- Can Keep schema generation and insertion in the same file
- Can specify multiple files

  `spring.datasource.data = classpath:/abc.sql,classpath:/abc2.sql`

***NOTE:***

- For schema generation and insertion in the same file do not use `spring.datasource.data`, we have to use `spring.datasource.schema`
- Keep all files in *src/main/resources*
- set `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`

---

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
debug=true

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=docker
spring.datasource.data = classpath:/import.sql

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```